# Python infinite loop is getting stuck

Tags: python, loops, file, infinite-loop, text-processing

I am writing a program which is monitoring a log file for new data, and perform some analytics on it.
The logic is as follows

```
import time

class LogReader():

    def __init__(self):
        self.logpath = "/path/to/log/file"
        pass

    def line_processing_function(self, line):
        """
        This function processes the line
        """
        # Do something
        return
    
    def read_file(self):
        with open(self.logpath) as f:
            return f.readlines()

    def run_main_loop(self):
        data = self.read_file()
        while True:
            time.sleep(1) 
            new_data = self.read_file()

            for line in new_data[len(data): ]:
                self.line_processing_function(line)
            
            data = new_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lr = LogReader()
    lr.run_main_loop()
```

This function works very well for most of the times, however sometimes, it gets "stuck", as in, it's caught in some other blocking loop of some sort. Pressing ^C sorts the issue, and the while loop returns, and the processing continues. I could not identify a pattern regarding when this is stuck, as it gets stuck on seemingly random parts of code.

I cannot give away the exact `line_processing_function`, but it involves very basic text matching, regex and sending requests.

My question is, where could be the problem originating from? Could it be because the log file (which is being written continuously by another program) is changing? Or is it a definite issue with the `line_processing_function`? Moreover, how can I go about further investigating this issue?

Comment: Your loop must have some break condition

Comment: As of now, it doesn't. It's quit by pressing ^C manually. Later, I plan to implement a flag, which will be checked in each iteration, which will decide when the loop is to be stopped.

Comment: Do you check new_data after read_file? What happens when it's not valid?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without more context. Most likely, the process you perform in your secret function is not the culprit, but rather the fact that you are reading an entire file as it may be written into by another process. Assuming the process that writes to the file is not destroying it, it would make more sense for you to keep the file open, and read from it using `read()`.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Yes, I do. However, since this is a Minimal, Reproducible Example, I did not find it necessary to include it. If the file isn't present, a FileNotFoundError is raised. If new data isn't written, ```data``` and ```new_data``` will be the same, so the inner for loop would not run, and the script would sleep for another second, and so on.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron I will try implementing it to see if keeping the file open solves the problem. Thank you